# Evaluating first-order arithmetic formulas

Tags: python, math, logic, package, arithmetic-expressions

Is there a python package for evaluating bounded first-order arithmetic formulas?

For example, it gets a bounded first-order arithmetic expression

```
>>> exp = 'forall x < z exists y < x ((2 * y + 1 = x) or (2 * y = x))'
```

and a value for the free variable z

```
>>> tau = [(z,20)]
```

and returns its value

```
>>> eval(exp, tau)  
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is something called "quantifier elimination". If so, take a look at QEPCAD. [1] It may be easier to create a Python interface for QEPCAD than to find a Python implementation.

[1] http://www.usna.edu/CS/~qepcad/B/QEPCAD.html